# python : syntax for accessing the return result of the non static function

Tags: python, function, arguments

What is the syntax for accessing the return result of the non static function passed in another function as an argument without calling that function again in python?

Example:

```
def func(a,b):
    return (a+b)
def compute(func)
    # what to write here so as to access return value here without calling func
```

Is it possible ??

Comment: you want to get result of function passed as argument without calling it? what for?

Comment: If you don't call it, there's no return value. What's more, the return value depends on the parameters (which you don't seem to have). The real question here is: _Why do you want to avoid calling the function? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?_

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the return value without calling the function. Furthermore, your function requires parameters, therefore you **need** to call the function before you can get a definite return value.

You may also need to change the parameter name, as 'func' is the name of your function and your parameter.

Call it like so:

```
def compute(newParamName):
    func(num1, num2)
```